# How do I add a new root folder to specific drive?

Tags: filesystem, hard-drive

I have /var on a separate drive and now I want to add /backup to that same drive. How would I do that?

When I installed Ubuntu, I put / on an 80 GB drive and had a 250 GB drive use /var. I want my backups to reside on the 250 GB drive since they can take up quite a bit of space.

Comment: Do you want them as separate partitions or to link to separate paths on the same partition?

Comment: Separate paths on the same partition I guess.

Comment: Do You want to Mount the same device on multiple path ? If Yes, then its possible but not at all good idea. I would suggest you to link.

Comment: I clarified some on why I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specified you'd like them both to be on the same partition on that drive, I'll give you some pointers:

1. Your existing /var mount probably mounts the entire partition, ie the root of that partition.  You can therefore only do that once.
2. You could, however, have both a /var and a /backup on that partition, ie have both of them one level down.  So instead of the root of that partition being your /var, the root of your partition will *contain* a "var" and a "backup" directory.

   You would then need to mount that drive to one specific mount point, say /mnt/mydrive.

   Then, set up [bind mounts](http://backdrift.org/how-to-use-bind-mounts-in-linux) from /var and /backup to directories within your /mnt/mydrive, eg to /mnt/mydrive/var and /mnt/mydrive/backup.

   The use of bind mounts allows you to have them in your /etc/fstab just like a normal mount, but it allows you to mount only a particular directory, not the whole partition.

Comment: Would it mess stuff up if I add /var/backup then just create an alias at the root?

Comment: That is a good idea.  Keep in mind that a directory called */var/backups* is commonly used by certain software, so to avoid confusing the two very similar names you may want to consider a more unique name.  But that's up to you.  You could also put it as a subdirectory of /var/backups.  You could use it as it is there, or bind mount it to /backup as you originally wanted.